# Rails 4 how to upload the file and the file content into a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a demand,used rails 4 to upload the file,and i need save the file content into a database,file does not need to save.Now have no idea.I tried many way but failed to solve.Hope to get your help,thx.

Comment: You need to add a lot more context to this question. What code have you got, what methods have you tried, what kind of file is it, what data transformations are required?

Answer (score 1):

You can use gem like paperclip(https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip[paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)) or [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) as a sample model it will be like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar,
                    :storage => :database,
                    :styles => { :thumb => "75x75>", :small => "150x150>" },
                    :url => '/:class/:id/:attachment?style=:style'
end
```

in **storage** you can specify the kind of saving you want

Answer (score 0):

You can create a multipart form object. Please check the example below,

HTML View

```
<% form_for(:uploaded_file, @feed, :html=> {:multipart=>true}) do |f| %>  
  <p>
    <%= f.label :uploaded_file, 'Upload your file.' %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :uploaded_file %>
 </p>
 <p><%= f.submit 'upload' %></p>
<% end %>
```

Controller Action

```
file_data = params[:uploaded_file]
if file_data.respond_to?(:read)
  xml_contents = file_data.read
elsif file_data.respond_to?(:path)
  xml_contents = File.read(file_data.path)
else
  logger.error "Bad file_data: #{file_data.class.name}: # {file_data.inspect}"
end
```

Comment: I am using practically the same controller action as here to read from a non-rails upload (actually from R).  It worked fine while I was using R's library('httr') POST. When I at a later stage changed to postForm (RCurl package) both ruby methods file_data.respond_to?(:read) and file_data.respond_to?(:path) returned true, but only File.read(file_data.path) returned content. So I switched so that I start with the respond_to?(:path). No idea why. Took long to debug so hope this might lead someone on the right track faster than I found it.